# Grouping up students records in a Binary File in C++ Based on their Batch Number?

Tags: c++, sorting, console-application, binaryfiles, turbo-c++

im working on a console application in C++ (I'm a beginner) 
and the purpose is to make a small application that can store, read and modify students records

Now, i want to group up data of binary file (class9.dat) such that all the students with common batch id ( char type batch[5] ) should stuck together , by saying "stuck together", i mean 
if initially, consider binary file consider data in this form

```
[Tom , 2] 
[Harry, 1] 
[Peter, 2] 
[Stephen, 1]  
[Henry , 0]
```

then, after stucking data together (or grouping them up ) , data should be arranged in file as follow

```
[Tom , 2]
[Peter, 2] 
[Harry, 1]
[Stephen, 1]
[Henry , 0]
```

(note that the data is arranged in the order in which they are read/encountered first from top-to-bottom)

ok, now i tried myself alot and even i think i found a solution to this problem, i used concept of dynamic linked list (stack) to keep check whether a particular batch ID is arranged properly or not

below is a code snippet for the function void_update()

```
void update_files() 
{
    fin.open("class9.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);

    fout.open("temp.dat",ios::out|ios::binary);
    int total_records,pos,rec,temp;
    char temp_batch[5];
    fin.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    fin.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
    fin.seekg(0,ios::end);
    pos=fin.tellg();
    total_records=pos/sizeof(s);
    fin.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    rec=0;

    while(rec<total_records)
    {   fin.seekg(rec*sizeof(s),ios::beg);
        fin.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
        strcpy(temp_batch,s.get_char(3));
        temp=checklist(temp_batch); //function checks whether batch already in stack or not (either already sorted together or not)
        if(temp==0)
        {
            fin.seekg(0,ios::beg); //move to first record
            while(fin.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s)))
            {
                if(strcmpi(temp_batch,s.get_char(3))==0) //get_char(3) returns student batch id
                {
                    fout.write((char*)&s,sizeof(s));//writting copies of data to temp.dat where they are expected to be grouped together 
                }

            }
            push_to_stack(temp_batch);//SEND TEMP_BATCH TO STACK
        }
        rec++; 
    }
    fout.close();
    fin.close();
    delete_stacks(); //delete dynamic stack
    fin.open("temp.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);
    fout.open("class9.dat",ios::out|ios::binary);
    while(fin.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s)))//writting sorted data back into class9.dat file from temp.dat
    {
        fout.write((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
    }
    fin.close();
    fout.close();


}
```

This is the function code snippet, for your reference im leaving code-snippets of 2 other functions which are belonging to stacks 
here they are

```
struct node
{
    char batches[5];
    node *next;
}*start=NULL,*end=NULL, *temp;
void push_to_stack(char* b)
{
    temp=new(node);
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"FATAL ERROR : MEMORY OVERFLOW ";
        cout<<"\n YOUR SYSTEM RAN OUT OF MEMORY. PLEASE RESTART THE SYSTEM \n";
        cout<<"\n \n TERMINATING STUDENT DATA MANAGER !!!";
        getch();
        exit(0);
    }
    strcpy(temp->batches,b);
    temp->next=start;
    if(end==NULL)
    {
        end=temp;
    }
    start=temp;
}
int checklist(char *b)
{
    temp=start;
    while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            if(strcmpi(b,temp->batches)==0) //matched 
            {
                return 1;//yes ,BATCH IS EXIsTS
            }
            else temp=temp->next;

        }
    return 0;
}
void delete_stacks()
{   node *save;
    save=start;
    if(save==NULL)
        return;
    else
    while(start!=NULL)
    {
        save=start;
        if(save==NULL)
            break;
        start=start->next;
        delete(save);
    }
    return;
}
```

this is it, now let me tell you whats my approach to this problem

what im trying to do is basically i pass student's batch id to another char variable temp_batch , then i check if temp_batch aldready exists in my stack (which contain list of all batch ids on which function is already performed) 
if temp_batch do not exists in my stack then, it means that the data having batch id as temp_batch is not grouped up , so run a while-loop which read whole file from beg to end and when it found the record having batch id same as temp_batch, it is appended to temp.dat in this manner for every record on file, it is expected to group up records together. but this is not working 
whats problem is , when i run this code 
instead of grouping all records , it only GROUPS UP records of that BATCH ID which it encounter first, rest it ignores all other and do not send them to temp.dat 
example, consider above example, then this is the record which will be sended to temp.dat after whole process

```
[Tom , 2]
[Peter, 2]
```

please help me, i did alot of inspection of code , again and again but failed to get the problem... and yes, thanks for reading this whole question upto this point.

***EDIT / UPDATE TO QUESTION :*** 
some people also asked about "s" in fin/fout statements , here it is well 
s is object of class student as defined below

```
    class student
    {
        private:
            char name[50],address[100];
            char age[5];//this is a replacement
            char sub1[80],sub2[80];
            int standard;//int class
            char id[6];
            char mobile[16];
            char mobile2[16];
            char batch[5]; //this is the batch id im talking about, on basis of which records need to be grouped together


        public:
        /*1*/
            //--------------------------
            void getdata(int); //gets data, this is just declaration here
            int countname(char *names); // ignore this
            int countid(char *sid); //ignore this
            void showdata(); //ignore this
            void new_data(int);//ignore this 
            void changeclass(); //ignore this 

            //below is a function you might be interested in
            char *get_char(int code) // 0 (ID) , 1(AGE) , 2 (NAME) , 3(BATCH)
            {
                if(code==0)
                    return id; //char
                else if(code==1)
                    return age; //char
                else if(code==2)
                    return name;
                else if(code==3)
                    return batch;
            }
 //this function below returns student's standard (or class in common language day to day life)
            int get_class()
            {   return standard;
            }
            //--------------------------

    }s; //end of class , created object s for student
```

Comment: I find your algorithm quite complicated. What I would personally do is to store my student names into a `map<int,vector<string> >` where the key of the map is your batch id and the `vector<string>` contains all the names of the students corresponding to that batch id. When you finish that, your students would actually be already grouped up.

Comment: Im using an old compiler which don't allow use of vector, can you suggest me whats wrong in the algorithm shown above by performing a quick dry run , i did it so many times failed to understand why such problem is occuring (even though its complicated , poor and not so fast algorithm )   
Also, i don't want to use what you mentioned above probably because i don't know STL very well at this moment (beginner) and learning it side-by-side

Comment: Please , i request all to only point out mistake in the algorithm mentioned in question , i just want to know the mistake in the above program. 
thank you once again for reading and responding to my post :)

Comment: @KeshavSharma:  Upgrade your compiler.  There are many free versions to download, such as G++ and Visual Studio Express.  You have no excuses.  If the class requires the old Turbo C++ or Borland C++, walk away.

Comment: Is your file actually binary or is it in text?  Open the file in a text editor.  If it can be read easily, it is a text file.  If the file is in binary, are you using a delimiter for the text field (such as '\0') or are you going by a maximum field width?

Comment: I'd like to help, but the code you posted does not compile.  For example, in the `update_files` function, there is the statement `fin.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s));`, but I don't see any `s` variable prior to the statement.

Comment: When you used the TurboC++ debugger and executed each statement singly, which statement is causing the issue?  What are the values associated with the variables in the statement?

Comment: Ok, im not using turboc++ im using devcpp  and yes , i can't able to identify which statement causing issue, its a binary file and the data shown in question inside [ ] is merely showing an example not actual representation of data ( s ) 
" s " is a object of class student , see question (im updating it) for class student

Comment: Also , Sir thomas mathews, its a Binary File no text file touched anywhere in whole program, just binary thats it :)

Comment: BTW, newer versions of [dev-c++](https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/) are c++11 compliant and still free.

Comment: please help me with the que ? :(