# Binary file seekg() pointer not working properly ? C++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

```
fin.seekg(rec*sizeof(s),ios::beg);
fin.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
```

where "s" is a object of class student, problem is that for int rec=0 
im able to read object s in a binary file at 0th position
but when i do rec++; and then run the 2 codes above again, then im unable to read next object, (i mean , s.get_data() still returns data of 1st object s in file instead of returning data of 1*sizeof(s) or next record) 
what im doing wrong ?

Comment: [The problem is in the code you aren't showing.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: problem is these 2 lines, i did a dry run and found out that these 2 lines of code not working as they should be 
i stored data in following manner in my binary file 

A 
B
A 

where A,B are object "s" with different data encapsulated

Comment: the actual code is quite big, if you want to see the original problem (i posted before) follow this link please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335823/grouping-up-students-records-in-a-binary-file-in-c-based-on-their-batch-number?noredirect=1#comment60305826_36335823 

but i did placed some cout statements for dry run and im 90% sure that problem is due to these 2 statements, refer to link for more code

Comment: "the actual code is quite big" Then you need to read the link I posted again, if you're having issues reading and writing to a file it can be summed up in just a few lines of code, the added bonus of taking the time to strip your question down to the bare metal is you'll often find a solution during the process.